# replacing a character by another character using chr and ord

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that encrypts the text message entered by the user
The program gets the ascii value of each character entered by the user and replaces the
character with a character with ascii value three more than the original character
For example, character with upper case 'A' (ascii - 65) is replaced by character 'D' (ascii - 68). I don't see how this can work. What should I do?

The sample outcome:
Enter a message: This is a secret message

The encrypted message is: Wklv#lv#d#vhfuhw#phvvdjh1

I trying using the following code but it doesn't work with more than 1 string:
char1 = 'A'
char2 =(ord(char1)+3)

num1 = char2
print(chr(num1))

Comment: You must iterate over your string and replace characters one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Using ord and chr is one way to do this:

```
def encode(s):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(c)+3) for c in s)
print(encode('abc'))
```

**Output:**

```
def
```

Comment: That's **exactly** what my Answer will give you

Comment: Got it. It works. Thank you.